# Retrieve constrained list from knowledge base

Tags: list, prolog

```
step('pancakes', 1, 'mix butter and sugar in a bowl', [butter, sugar], ['bowl']). 
step('pancakes', 2, 'add eggs', [eggs], []). 
step('pancakes', 3, 'mix flour and bakingpowder', [flour, baking_powder], []).

steps(R,Y,P):-
     findall(A,step(R,_,A,_,P),Z),
     distinctSteps(Z,Y).

distinctSteps(Z,Y) :-
     list_to_set(Z,Y).
```

So I have this knowledge base and a rule that should retrieve the step with the certain utensil I give as a parameter. So for example `steps('pancakes', bowl, I).` should return `I = ['mix butter and sugar in a bowl']`. However, it just gives `false`. If I reduce it to just `R,Y` it works, but that's not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your predicates should start with small letters, so Step(...) should be step(...). Words starting with capitals are reserved for variables.

Comment: That does not fix it though

Comment: I'll try to fix it after lunch

Comment: cheers man, no hurry

Comment: look at the order of arguments to `steps/3`. also, `bowl` is not `[bowl]`. either enclose `bowl` in brackets or use `memberchk/2`.

Comment: the quotes around `bowl` are not necessary. only if what's inside the quotes becomes an invalid atom, then the quotes are necessary, like if there's a space inside, or if it starts with a capital letter (and would be interpreted as logical variable without the quotes). try `'bowl' = bowl.`, it returns **`true`**. by brackets I meant `[` and `]`. :)

Comment: Well I found out that it is because I am asking steps('pancakes', bowl, I). If I do steps('pancakes', ['bowl'], I). It works, but I don't want it in that way. And also the utensil list can consist of multiple elements and in that case it would also not work.

Comment: @Coderman without the `@` there is no notifications. I did not know that you responded, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there might be a misunderstanding. Is your ingredients term an atom (`bowl`) or a list (`[bowl]`)? I'm asking because this is the knowledge base I came up with, but I'm not sure if this meets your requirements. So I assume you use a list of utensils. Please note that the following knowledge base differs from yours (and as a result the questions as well):

```
step(pancakes, 1, 'mix butter and sugar', [butter, sugar], [bowl, mixer]). 
step(pancakes, 2, 'add eggs', [eggs], []). 
step(pancakes, 3, 'mix flour and bakingpowder', [flour, bakingpowder], [bowl]). 

hasUtensil(Dish, Step, Instr, Ingr, Utensil):-
    step(Dish, Step, Instr, Ingr, U),
    member(Utensil, U).

stepsUtensil(Dish,Utensil,Instructs):-
    findall(A, hasUtensil(Dish,_,A,_,Utensil), Instructs).

?- stepsUtensil(pancakes, bowl, I).
I = ['mix butter and sugar', 'mix flour and bakingpowder']
```

`stepsUtensil/5` does simply unlist all utensils from the utensil list from `step/5`. It does it by just asking for all members in the utensil list. For example for the first step:

```
?- hasUtensil(_,1,_,_,U).
U = bowl ;
U = mixer ;
false.
```

If you would write `hasUtensil/5` as a fact it would look as follows:

```
step(pancakes, 1, 'mix butter and sugar', [butter, sugar], bowl). 
step(pancakes, 1, 'mix butter and sugar', [butter, sugar], mixer). 
step(pancakes, 3, 'mix flour and bakingpowder', [flour, bakingpowder], bowl).
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. The utensils are indeed in a list so for example ['bowl', 'mixer'] yes. Could you maybe explain what the Utensil function does and why it works now without having to give the input as list? Thanks in advance